# Tensorflow Object Detection API mnaspfn head semi error during training

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection-api

I am currently trying to train a transfer learning model with the tf object detection API.
I chose the `ssd_mobilenet_v2_mnasfpn_coco` from the [Model Zoo](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/detection_model_zoo.md) from Tensorflow.
I installed all the dependencies and tested it with the python file from the docs.

In the past, I trained a different model, which worked, but I had some trouble getting one model to run in the end. I succeeded at some point and used the same set of commands for training as I do now.

But when I run the training/graph creation (for transforming it to a tflite model) for my mnaspfn model via:

```sh
python object_detection/legacy/train.py
python object_detection/export_tflite_ssd_graph.py
```

I get the following error/warning:

```
>     WARNING:tensorflow:From /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tf_slim/layers/layers.py:1089:
> Layer.apply (from tensorflow.python.keras.engine.base_layer) is
> deprecated and will be removed in a future version. Instructions for
> updating: Please use `layer.__call__` method instead. W0628
> 11:19:43.432508 140522432427904 deprecation.py:323] From
> /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tf_slim/layers/layers.py:1089:
> Layer.apply (from tensorflow.python.keras.engine.base_layer) is
> deprecated and will be removed in a future version. Instructions for
> updating: Please use `layer.__call__` method instead.
> ERROR:tensorflow:C6: Tensor("FeatureExtractor/MnasFPN/Identity:0",
> shape=(1, 5, 5, 48), dtype=float32) E0628 11:19:45.003035
> 140522432427904 ssd_mobilenet_v2_mnasfpn_feature_extractor.py:396] C6:
> Tensor("FeatureExtractor/MnasFPN/Identity:0", shape=(1, 5, 5, 48),
> dtype=float32) ERROR:tensorflow:layer_1:
> Tensor("FeatureExtractor/MobilenetV2/Conv/Relu6:0", shape=(1, 160,
> 160, 32), dtype=float32) E0628 11:19:45.003337 140522432427904
> ssd_mobilenet_v2_mnasfpn_feature_extractor.py:396] layer_1:
> Tensor("FeatureExtractor/MobilenetV2/Conv/Relu6:0", shape=(1, 160,
> 160, 32), dtype=float32) ERROR:tensorflow:layer_10:
> Tensor("FeatureExtractor/MobilenetV2/expanded_conv_8/output:0",
> shape=(1, 20, 20, 64), dtype=float32) E0628 11:19:45.003476
> 140522432427904 ssd_mobilenet_v2_mnasfpn_feature_extractor.py:396]
> layer_10:
> Tensor("FeatureExtractor/MobilenetV2/expanded_conv_8/output:0",
> shape=(1, 20, 20, 64), dtype=float32)
> ERROR:tensorflow:layer_10/depthwise_output:
> Tensor("FeatureExtractor/MobilenetV2/expanded_conv_8/depthwise_output:0",
> shape=(1, 20, 20, 384), dtype=float32) E0628 11:19:45.003618
> 140522432427904 ssd_mobilenet_v2_mnasfpn_feature_extractor.py:396]
> layer_10/depthwise_output:
> Tensor("FeatureExtractor/MobilenetV2/expanded_conv_8/depthwise_output:0",
> shape=(1, 20, 20, 384), dtype=float32)
> ERROR:tensorflow:layer_10/expansion_output:
> Tensor("FeatureExtractor/MobilenetV2/expanded_conv_8/expansion_output:0",
> shape=(1, 20, 20, 384), dtype=float32) E0628 11:19:45.003799
> 140522432427904 ssd_mobilenet_v2_mnasfpn_feature_extractor.py:396]
> layer_10/expansion_output:
> Tensor("FeatureExtractor/MobilenetV2/expanded_conv_8/expansion_output:0",
> shape=(1, 20, 20, 384), dtype=float32)
> ERROR:tensorflow:layer_10/output:
> Tensor("FeatureExtractor/MobilenetV2/expanded_conv_8/output:0",
> shape=(1, 20, 20, 64), dtype=float32) E0628 11:19:45.003912
> 140522432427904 ssd_mobilenet_v2_mnasfpn_feature_extractor.py:396]
> layer_10/output:
> Tensor("FeatureExtractor/MobilenetV2/expanded_conv_8/output:0",
> shape=(1, 20, 20, 64), dtype=float32) ERROR:tensorflow:layer_11:
> Tensor("FeatureExtractor/MobilenetV2/expanded_conv_9/output:0",
> shape=(1, 20, 20, 64), dtype=float32) E0628 11:19:45.004024
> 140522432427904 ssd_mobilenet_v2_mnasfpn_feature_extractor.py:396]
> layer_11:
> Tensor("FeatureExtractor/MobilenetV2/expanded_conv_9/output:0",
> shape=(1, 20, 20, 64), dtype=float32)
> ERROR:tensorflow:layer_11/depthwise_output:
> Tensor("FeatureExtractor/MobilenetV2/expanded_conv_9/depthwise_output:0",
> shape=(1, 20, 20, 384), dtype=float32) E0628 11:19:45.004132
> 140522432427904 ssd_mobilenet_v2_mnasfpn_feature_extractor.py:396]
> layer_11/depthwise_output:
> Tensor("FeatureExtractor/MobilenetV2/expanded_conv_9/depthwise_output:0",
> shape=(1, 20, 20, 384), dtype=float32)
> ERROR:tensorflow:layer_11/expansion_output:
> Tensor("FeatureExtractor/MobilenetV2/expanded_conv_9/expansion_output:0",
> shape=(1, 20, 20, 384), dtype=float32) E0628 11:19:45.004241
> 140522432427904 ssd_mobilenet_v2_mnasfpn_feature_extractor.py:396]
> layer_11/expansion_output:
> Tensor("FeatureExtractor/MobilenetV2/expanded_conv_9/expansion_output:0",
> shape=(1, 20, 20, 384), dtype=float32)
> ERROR:tensorflow:layer_11/output:
> Tensor("FeatureExtractor/MobilenetV2/expanded_conv_9/output:0",
> shape=(1, 20, 20, 64), dtype=float32) E0628 11:19:45.004343
> 140522432427904 ssd_mobilenet_v2_mnasfpn_feature_extractor.py:396]
> layer_11/output:
> Tensor("FeatureExtractor/MobilenetV2/expanded_conv_9/output:0",
> shape=(1, 20, 20, 64), dtype=float32) ERROR:tensorflow:layer_12:
> Tensor("FeatureExtractor/MobilenetV2/expanded_conv_10/output:0",
> shape=(1, 20, 20, 96), dtype=float32) E0628 11:19:45.004450
> 140522432427904 ssd_mobilenet_v2_mnasfpn_feature_extractor.py:396]
> layer_12:
> Tensor("FeatureExtractor/MobilenetV2/expanded_conv_10/output:0",
> shape=(1, 20, 20, 96), dtype=float32)
> ERROR:tensorflow:layer_12/depthwise_output:
> Tensor("FeatureExtractor/MobilenetV2/expanded_conv_10/depthwise_output:0",
> shape=(1, 20, 20, 384), dtype=float32) E0628 11:19:45.004577
> 140522432427904 ssd_mobilenet_v2_mnasfpn_feature_extractor.py:396]
> layer_12/depthwise_output:
> Tensor("FeatureExtractor/MobilenetV2/expanded_conv_10/depthwise_output:0",
> shape=(1, 20, 20, 384), dtype=float32)
> ERROR:tensorflow:layer_12/expansion_output:
> Tensor("FeatureExtractor/MobilenetV2/expanded_conv_10/expansion_output:0",
> shape=(1, 20, 20, 384), dtype=float32) E0628 11:19:45.004697
> 140522432427904 ssd_mobilenet_v2_mnasfpn_feature_extractor.py:396]
> layer_12/expansion_output:
> Tensor("FeatureExtractor/MobilenetV2/expanded_conv_10/expansion_output:0",
> shape=(1, 20, 20, 384), dtype=float32)
> ERROR:tensorflow:layer_12/output:
> Tensor("FeatureExtractor/MobilenetV2/expanded_conv_10/output:0",
> shape=(1, 20, 20, 96), dtype=float32) E0628 11:19:45.004810
> 140522432427904 ssd_mobilenet_v2_mnasfpn_feature_extractor.py:396]
> layer_12/output:
> Tensor("FeatureExtractor/MobilenetV2/expanded_conv_10/output:0",
> shape=(1, 20, 20, 96), dtype=float32) ERROR:tensorflow:layer_13:
> Tensor("FeatureExtractor/MobilenetV2/expanded_conv_11/output:0",
> shape=(1, 20, 20, 96), dtype=float32) E0628 11:19:45.004933
> 140522432427904 ssd_mobilenet_v2_mnasfpn_feature_extractor.py:396]
> layer_13:
> Tensor("FeatureExtractor/MobilenetV2/expanded_conv_11/output:0",
> shape=(1, 20, 20, 96), dtype=float32)
> ERROR:tensorflow:layer_13/depthwise_output:
> Tensor("FeatureExtractor/MobilenetV2/expanded_conv_11/depthwise_output:0",
> shape=(1, 20, 20, 576), dtype=float32) E0628 11:19:45.005046
> 140522432427904 ssd_mobilenet_v2_mnasfpn_feature_extractor.py:396]
> layer_13/depthwise_output:
> Tensor("FeatureExtractor/MobilenetV2/expanded_conv_11/depthwise_output:0",
> shape=(1, 20, 20, 576), dtype=float32)
> ERROR:tensorflow:layer_13/expansion_output:
> Tensor("FeatureExtractor/MobilenetV2/expanded_conv_11/expansion_output:0",
> shape=(1, 20, 20, 576), dtype=float32) E0628 11:19:45.005153
> 140522432427904 ssd_mobilenet_v2_mnasfpn_feature_extractor.py:396]
> layer_13/expansion_output:
> Tensor("FeatureExtractor/MobilenetV2/expanded_conv_11/expansion_output:0",
> shape=(1, 20, 20, 576), dtype=float32)
> ERROR:tensorflow:layer_13/output:
> Tensor("FeatureExtractor/MobilenetV2/expanded_conv_11/output:0",
> shape=(1, 20, 20, 96), dtype=float32) E0628 11:19:45.005253
> 140522432427904 ssd_mobilenet_v2_mnasfpn_feature_extractor.py:396]
> layer_13/output:
> Tensor("FeatureExtractor/MobilenetV2/expanded_conv_11/output:0",
> shape=(1, 20, 20, 96), dtype=float32) ERROR:tensorflow:layer_14:
> Tensor("FeatureExtractor/MobilenetV2/expanded_conv_12/output:0",
> shape=(1, 20, 20, 96), dtype=float32) E0628 11:19:45.005365
> 140522432427904 ssd_mobilenet_v2_mnasfpn_feature_extractor.py:396]
> layer_14:
> Tensor("FeatureExtractor/MobilenetV2/expanded_conv_12/output:0",
> shape=(1, 20, 20, 96), dtype=float32)
> ERROR:tensorflow:layer_14/depthwise_output:
> Tensor("FeatureExtractor/MobilenetV2/expanded_conv_12/depthwise_output:0",
> shape=(1, 20, 20, 576), dtype=float32) E0628 11:19:45.005474
> 140522432427904 ssd_mobilenet_v2_mnasfpn_feature_extractor.py:396]
> layer_14/depthwise_output:
> Tensor("FeatureExtractor/MobilenetV2/expanded_conv_12/depthwise_output:0",
> shape=(1, 20, 20, 576), dtype=float32)
> ERROR:tensorflow:layer_14/expansion_output:
> Tensor("FeatureExtractor/MobilenetV2/expanded_conv_12/expansion_output:0",
> shape=(1, 20, 20, 576), dtype=float32) E0628 11:19:45.005624
> 140522432427904 ssd_mobilenet_v2_mnasfpn_feature_extractor.py:396]
> layer_14/expansion_output:
> Tensor("FeatureExtractor/MobilenetV2/expanded_conv_12/expansion_output:0",
> shape=(1, 20, 20, 576), dtype=float32)
> ERROR:tensorflow:layer_14/output:
> Tensor("FeatureExtractor/MobilenetV2/expanded_conv_12/output:0",
> shape=(1, 20, 20, 96), dtype=float32) E0628 11:19:45.005737
> 140522432427904 ssd_mobilenet_v2_mnasfpn_feature_extractor.py:396]
> layer_14/output:
> Tensor("FeatureExtractor/MobilenetV2/expanded_conv_12/output:0",
> shape=(1, 20, 20, 96), dtype=float32) ERROR:tensorflow:layer_15:
> Tensor("FeatureExtractor/MobilenetV2/expanded_conv_13/output:0",
> shape=(1, 10, 10, 160), dtype=float32) E0628 11:19:45.005845
> 140522432427904 ssd_mobilenet_v2_mnasfpn_feature_extractor.py:396]
> layer_15:
> Tensor("FeatureExtractor/MobilenetV2/expanded_conv_13/output:0",
> shape=(1, 10, 10, 160), dtype=float32)
> ERROR:tensorflow:layer_15/depthwise_output:
> Tensor("FeatureExtractor/MobilenetV2/expanded_conv_13/depthwise_output:0",
> shape=(1, 10, 10, 576), dtype=float32) E0628 11:19:45.005954
> 140522432427904 ssd_mobilenet_v2_mnasfpn_feature_extractor.py:396]
> layer_15/depthwise_output:
> Tensor("FeatureExtractor/MobilenetV2/expanded_conv_13/depthwise_output:0",
> shape=(1, 10, 10, 576), dtype=float32)
> ERROR:tensorflow:layer_15/expansion_output:
> Tensor("FeatureExtractor/MobilenetV2/expanded_conv_13/expansion_output:0",
> shape=(1, 20, 20, 576), dtype=float32) E0628 11:19:45.006059
> 140522432427904 ssd_mobilenet_v2_mnasfpn_feature_extractor.py:396]
> layer_15/expansion_output:
> Tensor("FeatureExtractor/MobilenetV2/expanded_conv_13/expansion_output:0",
> shape=(1, 20, 20, 576), dtype=float32)
> [...]
> ERROR:tensorflow:layer_9/depthwise_output:
> Tensor("FeatureExtractor/MobilenetV2/expanded_conv_7/depthwise_output:0",
> shape=(1, 20, 20, 384), dtype=float32) E0628 11:19:45.103541
> 140522432427904 ssd_mobilenet_v2_mnasfpn_feature_extractor.py:396]
> layer_9/depthwise_output:
> Tensor("FeatureExtractor/MobilenetV2/expanded_conv_7/depthwise_output:0",
> shape=(1, 20, 20, 384), dtype=float32)
> ERROR:tensorflow:layer_9/expansion_output:
> Tensor("FeatureExtractor/MobilenetV2/expanded_conv_7/expansion_output:0",
> shape=(1, 20, 20, 384), dtype=float32) E0628 11:19:45.103683
> 140522432427904 ssd_mobilenet_v2_mnasfpn_feature_extractor.py:396]
> layer_9/expansion_output:
> Tensor("FeatureExtractor/MobilenetV2/expanded_conv_7/expansion_output:0",
> shape=(1, 20, 20, 384), dtype=float32)
> ERROR:tensorflow:layer_9/output:
> Tensor("FeatureExtractor/MobilenetV2/expanded_conv_7/output:0",
> shape=(1, 20, 20, 64), dtype=float32) E0628 11:19:45.103810
> 140522432427904 ssd_mobilenet_v2_mnasfpn_feature_extractor.py:396]
> layer_9/output:
> Tensor("FeatureExtractor/MobilenetV2/expanded_conv_7/output:0",
> shape=(1, 20, 20, 64), dtype=float32) 2020-06-28 11:19:48.728455: I
> tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44]
> Successfully opened dynamic library libcuda.so.1 2020-06-28
> 11:19:48.732131: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:318]
> failed call to cuInit: CUDA_ERROR_NO_DEVICE: no CUDA-capable device is
> detected 2020-06-28 11:19:48.732181: I
> tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:156] kernel driver
> does not appear to be running on this host (bf80455718a0):
> /proc/driver/nvidia/version does not exist 2020-06-28 11:19:48.732628:
> I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:142] Your CPU supports
> instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2
> FMA 2020-06-28 11:19:48.740029: I
> tensorflow/core/platform/profile_utils/cpu_utils.cc:94] CPU Frequency:
> 2300000000 Hz 2020-06-28 11:19:48.740310: I
> tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:168] XLA service 0x16e3640
> initialized for platform Host (this does not guarantee that XLA will
> be used). Devices: 2020-06-28 11:19:48.740347: I
> tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:176]   StreamExecutor
> device (0): Host, Default Version INFO:tensorflow:Found and fixed 12
> matches I0628 11:19:49.103435 140522432427904 exporter.py:92] Found
> and fixed 12 matches INFO:tensorflow:Found and fixed 0 matches I0628
> 11:19:49.138400 140522432427904 exporter.py:92] Found and fixed 0
> matches WARNING:tensorflow:From
> /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/tools/freeze_graph.py:127:
> checkpoint_exists (from
> tensorflow.python.training.checkpoint_management) is deprecated and
> will be removed in a future version. Instructions for updating: Use
> standard file APIs to check for files with this prefix. W0628
> 11:19:49.809565 140522432427904 deprecation.py:323] From
> /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/tools/freeze_graph.py:127:
> checkpoint_exists (from
> tensorflow.python.training.checkpoint_management) is deprecated and
> will be removed in a future version. Instructions for updating: Use
> standard file APIs to check for files with this prefix.
> INFO:tensorflow:Restoring parameters from /content/drive/My
> Drive/DeepSpace/models/mnasfpn/train/model.ckpt-100 I0628
> 11:19:50.725562 140522432427904 saver.py:1284] Restoring parameters
> from /content/drive/My
> Drive/DeepSpace/models/mnasfpn/train/model.ckpt-100
> WARNING:tensorflow:From
> /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/tools/freeze_graph.py:233:
> convert_variables_to_constants (from
> tensorflow.python.framework.graph_util_impl) is deprecated and will be
> removed in a future version. Instructions for updating: Use
> `tf.compat.v1.graph_util.convert_variables_to_constants` W0628
> 11:19:52.092961 140522432427904 deprecation.py:323] From
> /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/tools/freeze_graph.py:233:
> convert_variables_to_constants (from
> tensorflow.python.framework.graph_util_impl) is deprecated and will be
> removed in a future version. Instructions for updating: Use
> `tf.compat.v1.graph_util.convert_variables_to_constants`
> WARNING:tensorflow:From
> /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/graph_util_impl.py:277:
> extract_sub_graph (from tensorflow.python.framework.graph_util_impl)
> is deprecated and will be removed in a future version. Instructions
> for updating: Use `tf.compat.v1.graph_util.extract_sub_graph` W0628
> 11:19:52.093257 140522432427904 deprecation.py:323] From
> /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/graph_util_impl.py:277:
> extract_sub_graph (from tensorflow.python.framework.graph_util_impl)
> is deprecated and will be removed in a future version. Instructions
> for updating: Use `tf.compat.v1.graph_util.extract_sub_graph`
> INFO:tensorflow:Froze 658 variables. I0628 11:19:52.769557
> 140522432427904 graph_util_impl.py:334] Froze 658 variables.
> INFO:tensorflow:Converted 658 variables to const ops. I0628
> 11:19:52.859092 140522432427904 graph_util_impl.py:394] Converted 658
> variables to const ops. 2020-06-28 11:19:53.012933: I
> tensorflow/tools/graph_transforms/transform_graph.cc:317] Applying
> strip_unused_nodes
```

It does not terminate my run and the model still kind of seems to work. But the results are completely terrible. I figure something while importing the model is going wrong, but as this error is not telling me what actually is wrong, its hard to figure out.
(I removed some lines of the Error message, as the character limit does not allow more, but should still be sufficient as the error seems to be the same throughout)

I am using the config: `ssd_mobilenet_v2_mnasfpn_shared_box_predictor_320x320_coco_sync.config` from [samples/config](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/object_detection/samples/configs). I modified it to fit my dataset and changed the label paths etc.

```
# SSD with MnasFPN feature extractor, shared box predictor
# See Chen et al, https://arxiv.org/abs/1912.01106
# Trained on COCO, initialized from scratch.
#
# 0.92B MulAdds, 2.5M Parameters. Latency is 193ms on Pixel 1.
# Achieves 26.6 mAP on COCO14 minival dataset.

# This config is TPU compatible

model {
  ssd {
    inplace_batchnorm_update: true
    freeze_batchnorm: false
    num_classes: 4
    box_coder {
      faster_rcnn_box_coder {
        y_scale: 10.0
        x_scale: 10.0
        height_scale: 5.0
        width_scale: 5.0
      }
    }
    matcher {
      argmax_matcher {
        matched_threshold: 0.5
        unmatched_threshold: 0.5
        ignore_thresholds: false
        negatives_lower_than_unmatched: true
        force_match_for_each_row: true
        use_matmul_gather: true
      }
    }
    similarity_calculator {
      iou_similarity {
      }
    }
    encode_background_as_zeros: true
    anchor_generator {
      multiscale_anchor_generator {
        min_level: 3
        max_level: 6
        anchor_scale: 3.0
        aspect_ratios: [1.0, 2.0, 0.5]
        scales_per_octave: 3
      }
    }
    image_resizer {
      fixed_shape_resizer {
        height: 320
        width: 320
      }
    }
    box_predictor {
      weight_shared_convolutional_box_predictor {
        depth: 64
        class_prediction_bias_init: -4.6
        conv_hyperparams {
          activation: RELU_6,
          regularizer {
            l2_regularizer {
              weight: 0.00004
            }
          }
          initializer {
            random_normal_initializer {
              stddev: 0.01
              mean: 0.0
            }
          }
          batch_norm {
            scale: true,
            decay: 0.997,
            epsilon: 0.001,
          }
        }
        num_layers_before_predictor: 4
        share_prediction_tower: true
        use_depthwise: true
        kernel_size: 3
      }
    }
    feature_extractor {
      type: 'ssd_mobilenet_v2_mnasfpn'
      fpn {
        min_level: 3
        max_level: 6
        additional_layer_depth: 48
      }
      min_depth: 16
      depth_multiplier: 1.0
      conv_hyperparams {
        activation: RELU_6,
        regularizer {
          l2_regularizer {
            weight: 0.00004
          }
        }
        initializer {
          random_normal_initializer {
            stddev: 0.01
            mean: 0.0
          }
        }
        batch_norm {
          scale: true,
          decay: 0.97,
          epsilon: 0.001,
        }
      }
      override_base_feature_extractor_hyperparams: true
    }
    loss {
      classification_loss {
        weighted_sigmoid_focal {
          alpha: 0.25
          gamma: 2.0
        }
      }
      localization_loss {
        weighted_smooth_l1 {
        }
      }
      classification_weight: 1.0
      localization_weight: 1.0
    }
    normalize_loss_by_num_matches: true
    normalize_loc_loss_by_codesize: true
    post_processing {
      batch_non_max_suppression {
        score_threshold: 1e-8
        iou_threshold: 0.6
        max_detections_per_class: 100
        max_total_detections: 100
      }
      score_converter: SIGMOID
    }
  }
}

train_config: {
  batch_size: 1024
  sync_replicas: true
  startup_delay_steps: 0
  replicas_to_aggregate: 32
  num_steps: 100                # TODO edit number steps here (maybe)
  data_augmentation_options {
    random_horizontal_flip {
    }
  }
  data_augmentation_options {
    random_crop_image {
      min_object_covered: 0.0
      min_aspect_ratio: 0.75
      max_aspect_ratio: 3.0
      min_area: 0.75
      max_area: 1.0
      overlap_thresh: 0.0
    }
  }
  optimizer {
    momentum_optimizer: {
      learning_rate: {
        cosine_decay_learning_rate {
          learning_rate_base: 4.
          total_steps: 100          # TODO and here as well
          warmup_learning_rate: .026666
          warmup_steps: 50          # TODO and here asle
        }
      }
      momentum_optimizer_value: 0.9
    }
    use_moving_average: false
  }
  max_number_of_boxes: 100
  unpad_groundtruth_tensors: false
  fine_tune_checkpoint: "{PATH}"
  from_detection_checkpoint: true
}

train_input_reader: {
  tf_record_input_reader {
    input_path: "{PATH}"
  }
  label_map_path: "{PATH}"
}

eval_config: {
  metrics_set: "coco_detection_metrics"
  use_moving_averages: false
  num_examples: 182
}

eval_input_reader: {
  tf_record_input_reader {
    input_path: "{PATH}"
  }
  label_map_path: "{PATH}"
  shuffle: false
  num_readers: 1
}
```

Mainly I added:

```
  fine_tune_checkpoint: "{PATH}"
  from_detection_checkpoint: true
```

To the config and I am not sure if this is how you do it, as it may have changed over versions.
But I tested it without these parameters, still got the same ERROR messages and saw that the loss during training changed drastically, so the loading from checkpoint seems to be working here and does not seem to be the problem.

I am currently running on tf version 1.15, as 2.2 is not supported by the API yet. This might cause a problem, as the mnaspfn head is quite new (~3 months) and might be intended for 2.2.
But as it still runs without any import issues, this also does not seem to be the issue.

I am looking forward for any suggestions on this problem.

Comment: I am also facing exactly same issue. Anyone can assist here how to fix the training??